# How do I know the progress of the relocatesstables command

Tags: cassandra

I imported data from a three-node cluster to a 5-node cluster using the sstablesloader. Later, I found that some data was randomly lost。
[sstableloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcBbo.png)

Now the original snapshot backup is placed on the first three nodes of the 5-node cluster. The original cluster data directory is data1-data6, and the current data directory is data1-data10. In order to better utilize the disk performance, after the refresh is completed, I executed the relocatesstables command on the first three nodes
[refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhsCg.png)

The command was executed on the morning of November 27th, and now it has already been December 1st. I cannot know the execution progress accurately. I can only confirm that the program is still running through the ps command or by checking the debug log

```
/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/nodetool  relocatesstables kairosdb
```

[debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNc8w.png)

[ps command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QovWL.png)

The order has been in place for five days and I don't know how long it will take to finish

By the way, can I start writing data to clusters before the "relocate stables" command is finished, because the data compression time is too long

Comment: Please don't post errors or messages as images. If it's necessary content for the question, add it as text and format it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I seldom come to this forum, I don't know this rule, I will try to describe it in words in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right, I think this operation is considered a "compaction," so try running `nodetool compactionstats` to get an estimate on progress.